# query to read child table rows for each parent table id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a parent table A and child table B.

```
Parent Table A
---------------
AID,
AName,
Acode

Child Table B
-------------
AID,
BID,
BName,
BCode
```

I'm trying to form a query to retrieve rows from A, and corresponding rows from B for each AID. So basically result is all rows of A and the rows of B for each AID. I hope I make sense. Do I need to use joins for this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will use a `JOIN` between the tables:

```
select a.aid,
  a.aname,
  a.acode,
  b.bname,
  b.bcode
from tableA a
inner join tableB b
  on a.aid = b.aid
```

The `JOIN` will be between the `aid` from `tableA` and the `aid` from `tableB`. I used an `INNER JOIN` which will return all rows that exist in both tables.  If you want to return all rows from `tableA` even if there is not a matching row in `tableB`, then you will use a `LEFT JOIN`.

If you need help learning join  syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do.

> select a.*, b.* from tableA a inner join TableB b on a.AID = b.AID;